# Como saber a intensidade dos pixels numa determinada linha ou coluna de um cv::Mat?? [opencv][c++]

Tags: c++, matriz, opencv, vector, pixels

Estou com um projeto onde há necessidade de analise da intensidade dos pixels de uma determinada coluna ou linha, ou seja, minha função será intensity(cv::Mat m, int ref, std::string "lico") com uma sáida do tipo vetor com os dados da linhaou coluna desejada. Sou novato no opencv e c++.
Tenho usado o seguinte código:

```
.hpp
     class fooTools
    {
     public: 
         static std::vector<int> intensity(cv::Mat src, int ref, std::string lico);
    };
.cpp
    int footools::intensity(cv::Mat src, int ref, std::string lico)
    {
    //condicional para linha ou coluna
    if (lico == "linha") {
       for (int col = 0; col < (src.cols); col++)
            {
                std::cout << src.at<uchar>(ref,col);
            }
    }
    else if (lico == "coluna") {
        for (int row = 0; row < (src.rows); row++)
            {
                std::cout << src.at<uchar>(row, ref);
            }
        }
        return intensity;
    }
main

    int main() {      
    //load img
    std::string path = "C:/foo/";
    std::string name = "foo.bmp";
    cv::Mat src = cv::imread(path + name, cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

    fooTools::intensity(src, 44, "linha");
    }
```

não tenho tido saída alguma, e já tentei muita coisa, alguém pode me ajudar tem uma ideia pra essa situação.

Comment: amigo, formata o seu código que tu postou, que eu até tentei formatar, mas tá difícil de entender

Comment: Acredito que tenha melhorado, a intenção é passar a ideia, não tenho conseguido implementar essa ideia, 
ainda assim, obg pela atenção!

Comment: O que seria a variável ref?

Comment: ref é a linha ou coluna que quero acessar os pixels, por exemplo, intesity(cv::Mat m, 185, "linha"); logo, acessaria todos os pixels da linha 185 da imagem m. No caso, se mudo para intensity(cv::Mat m, 185,"coluna"); acessaria todos os pixels da coluna 185.